# Keyboard layout: US for numeric keypad, and SE for keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

On win7.

The Swedish (SE) numeric keyboard layout has a "," instead of "." as numeric separator character.

I want the numeric keyboard to give me "." when I press the "," key.
And I want to keep the rest of the keyboard working as a SE keyboard, so switching keyboards don't work.

Anyway to solve this ?

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows, you can use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22339) for this.

1. Download and install the program.
2. Go to `File -> Load Existing Keyboard...` and choose the Swedish layout.
3. Change the assignment for the decimal separator key.
4. Go to `Project -> Build DLL and Setup Package`.
5. Run the setup.

Comment: verified on win7.